# Is it possible forbid the switching of NSTabView

Tags: cocoa

I hope to forbid the switching of NSTabView. Is it possible?
When click the tab of NSTabView, what event does it trigger?
I can not found any sendaction relates to this.

Welcome any comment.

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement the `NSTabViewDelegate` method:

```
- (BOOL)tabView:(NSTabView *)tabView shouldSelectTabViewItem:(NSTabViewItem *)tabViewItem
```